# Как изменить цвет svg, расположенного выше background

Tags: html, css, svg

есть у меня вот такой код:

```
<div class="test">
        <div class="test2">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 283.5 27.8" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice">
                <path class="elementor-shape-fill" d="M0 0v6.7c1.9-.8 4.7-1.4 8.5-1 9.5 1.1 11.1 6 11.1 6s2.1-.7 4.3-.2c2.1.5 2.8 2.6 2.8 2.6s.2-.5 1.4-.7c1.2-.2 1.7.2 1.7.2s0-2.1 1.9-2.8c1.9-.7 3.6.7 3.6.7s.7-2.9 3.1-4.1 4.7 0 4.7 0 1.2-.5 2.4 0 1.7 1.4 1.7 1.4h1.4c.7 0 1.2.7 1.2.7s.8-1.8 4-2.2c3.5-.4 5.3 2.4 6.2 4.4.4-.4 1-.7 1.8-.9 2.8-.7 4 .7 4 .7s1.7-5 11.1-6c9.5-1.1 12.3 3.9 12.3 3.9s1.2-4.8 5.7-5.7c4.5-.9 6.8 1.8 6.8 1.8s.6-.6 1.5-.9c.9-.2 1.9-.2 1.9-.2s5.2-6.4 12.6-3.3c7.3 3.1 4.7 9 4.7 9s1.9-.9 4 0 2.8 2.4 2.8 2.4 1.9-1.2 4.5-1.2 4.3 1.2 4.3 1.2.2-1 1.4-1.7 2.1-.7 2.1-.7-.5-3.1 2.1-5.5 5.7-1.4 5.7-1.4 1.5-2.3 4.2-1.1c2.7 1.2 1.7 5.2 1.7 5.2s.3-.1 1.3.5c.5.4.8.8.9 1.1.5-1.4 2.4-5.8 8.4-4 7.1 2.1 3.5 8.9 3.5 8.9s.8-.4 2 0 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1-1.1 2.3-1.1 2.1.5 2.1.5 1.9-3.6 6.2-1.2 1.9 6.4 1.9 6.4 2.6-2.4 7.4 0c3.4 1.7 3.9 4.9 3.9 4.9s3.3-6.9 10.4-7.9 11.5 2.6 11.5 2.6.8 0 1.2.2c.4.2.9.9.9.9s4.4-3.1 8.3.2c1.9 1.7 1.5 5 1.5 5s.3-1.1 1.6-1.4c1.3-.3 2.3.2 2.3.2s-.1-1.2.5-1.9 1.9-.9 1.9-.9-4.7-9.3 4.4-13.4c5.6-2.5 9.2.9 9.2.9s5-6.2 15.9-6.2 16.1 8.1 16.1 8.1.7-.2 1.6-.4V0H0z"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <h1>Привет, мир!</h1>
    </div>
```

```
.test {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
}

.test2 {

}
```

Тут получается зеленый фон и сверху черная часть с SVG, как эту часть покрасить в белый?

Чтобы она сливалась со страницей, которая будет сверху

Answer (score 2):

Задайте классу, который стилизует path SVG, белый цвет

```
.elementor-shape-fill {
fill:white;

}
```

```css
.test {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
}

.test2 {

}
.elementor-shape-fill {
fill:white;

}
```

```html
<div class="test">
        <div class="test2">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 283.5 27.8" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice">
                <path class="elementor-shape-fill"  d="M0 0v6.7c1.9-.8 4.7-1.4 8.5-1 9.5 1.1 11.1 6 11.1 6s2.1-.7 4.3-.2c2.1.5 2.8 2.6 2.8 2.6s.2-.5 1.4-.7c1.2-.2 1.7.2 1.7.2s0-2.1 1.9-2.8c1.9-.7 3.6.7 3.6.7s.7-2.9 3.1-4.1 4.7 0 4.7 0 1.2-.5 2.4 0 1.7 1.4 1.7 1.4h1.4c.7 0 1.2.7 1.2.7s.8-1.8 4-2.2c3.5-.4 5.3 2.4 6.2 4.4.4-.4 1-.7 1.8-.9 2.8-.7 4 .7 4 .7s1.7-5 11.1-6c9.5-1.1 12.3 3.9 12.3 3.9s1.2-4.8 5.7-5.7c4.5-.9 6.8 1.8 6.8 1.8s.6-.6 1.5-.9c.9-.2 1.9-.2 1.9-.2s5.2-6.4 12.6-3.3c7.3 3.1 4.7 9 4.7 9s1.9-.9 4 0 2.8 2.4 2.8 2.4 1.9-1.2 4.5-1.2 4.3 1.2 4.3 1.2.2-1 1.4-1.7 2.1-.7 2.1-.7-.5-3.1 2.1-5.5 5.7-1.4 5.7-1.4 1.5-2.3 4.2-1.1c2.7 1.2 1.7 5.2 1.7 5.2s.3-.1 1.3.5c.5.4.8.8.9 1.1.5-1.4 2.4-5.8 8.4-4 7.1 2.1 3.5 8.9 3.5 8.9s.8-.4 2 0 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1 1.1-1.1 2.3-1.1 2.1.5 2.1.5 1.9-3.6 6.2-1.2 1.9 6.4 1.9 6.4 2.6-2.4 7.4 0c3.4 1.7 3.9 4.9 3.9 4.9s3.3-6.9 10.4-7.9 11.5 2.6 11.5 2.6.8 0 1.2.2c.4.2.9.9.9.9s4.4-3.1 8.3.2c1.9 1.7 1.5 5 1.5 5s.3-1.1 1.6-1.4c1.3-.3 2.3.2 2.3.2s-.1-1.2.5-1.9 1.9-.9 1.9-.9-4.7-9.3 4.4-13.4c5.6-2.5 9.2.9 9.2.9s5-6.2 15.9-6.2 16.1 8.1 16.1 8.1.7-.2 1.6-.4V0H0z"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <h1>Привет, мир!</h1>
    </div>
```